# How to monitor a list of process names and send email

Tags: bash, perl, shell, scripting, sh

I am trying to figure out the best way to monitor a list of process id's within a shell script. I don't want to monitor them all, just a custom list.

For example:
If I have process names::

```
Orange-TE--02
Orange-TE--03
Apple-JI--01
Orange-TE--09
Orange-JI--06
```

I am trying to write a script that will only Monitor Orange-TE--02, Apple-JI--01, Orange-JI--06 so if any of them goes down an email alert would be sent with the name of which process went down. if Orange-TE--03, Orange-TE--09 goes down, nothing happens.

Here is the output of the process'
process.sh -s

```
name            Process                         Pid
---------------- ------------------------------- ----
tneal01        Orange-JI--06                     3443
tneal01        Orange-TE--09                     2233
tneal01        Orange-JI--01                     5533
tneal01        Apple-TE--03                     9384
tneal01        Orange-TE--02                     4992
```

I was thinking about outputting the results to a file and have a list of expected process name, the ones that don't match send an email saying

```
Alert Process:
Apple-TE--03 
Orange-TE--02 
Are down
```

Not really sure how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**    There is also an answer to a follow-up question (that got put on hold and deleted)

---

With a Perl script

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

my @watch = qw(Orange-TE--02 Apple-JI--01 Orange-JI--06);

# Extract second column from the table of running processes, drop header line
my @running = map { (split)[1] } `process.sh -s`; 
shift @running;

my @down;
foreach my $proc_name (@watch) {
    push @down, $proc_name  if not grep { /^$proc_name$/ } @running;
}
print "$_ is down\n" for @down;
send_email(@down) if @down;

sub send_email {
    my @data = @_;
    # Write a file  (but use File::Temp) and attach for a multi-line message
    my $down_file = "services_down.$$";
    open my $fh, '>', $down_file  or die "Can't open $down_file: $!";
    print $fh "$_\n" for @data; 
    close $fh;
    my $cmd = "echo \"Services down: @data. See attached.\" | " .
        "mailx -a $down_file -s \"Services down\" user\@email";
    # Or, for an email with a single-line body
    # my $cmd = "echo @data | mailx -s \"Services down\"  user\@email";
    system($cmd) == 0  or do {
        warn "Error with system($cmd): $!";
        warn "File $down_file left behind for debugging. Remove.";
        return;
    };
    unlink $down_file  or warn "Can't unlink $down_file $!";
    return 1;
}
```

Notes on email.  If `mailx` is used we cannot pipe newlines into it. So if email needs to have service-per-line we can write to a file and attach the file to the message.  That file is removed, change that if you wish to keep it. I tag its name with the PID (`$$`), but *note that this isn't enough*  -- if there are multiple such files written in the process only the last one remains. Better use the core [File::Temp](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) for temporary files. Or use the commented-out version, with the whole body being in one line. Then there is no reason to write the file.

The error-checking on `system` will trigger only if there is a problem with running `$cmd`. If it runs fine but email itself fails (wrong address, for example), that likely won't be detected.

The alternative to all this is to use one of a number of modules for email.

Note that [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) and [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.416/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) have many useful routines, so the above can go as `if none { /.../ } @running;`. Here the improvement is subtle but often it is very direct.

I don't know how this should be monitored but you can put it in a loop such as

```
for (1..$max_time_steps) {
    # code above
    sleep 1;
}
```

Or you can have it inside of `while (1) { ... }` with a suitable condition for when to break out.

---

A variation of this got asked as a new question, which got put on hold (right as I completed entering code and an explanation of why I decide to answer it there) and is gone by now. See the end for how it differed. Here is the answer to *that* question.  The difference is shown at the end.

Use a hash for running processes returned by `process.sh -s`, where each process-name is a key with the value from the last column (PID/"Down"). The output of `process.sh` is fed into an array first in order to discard headers.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

my @watch = qw(Orange-TE--02 Apple-TE--03 Orange-JI--01);

my @procs_info = `process.sh -s`;
my %running = map { (split)[1,2] } @procs_info[2..$#procs_info]; 

print "$_ => $running{$_}\n" for keys %running;  # just to see it

my @down;
foreach my $proc_name (@watch) 
{
    push @down, $proc_name  
        if !exists $running{$proc_name} 
        or $running{$proc_name} eq 'Down';
}

if (@down) { 
    print "$_ is down\n" for @down;
    # send email
}
```

I add to `@down` a watched process if it isn't even on the list of running ones.  Change if wrong.

---

For the record, here is what is different in the other question (and how I tested)

```
my @procs_info = <DATA>;    # The only change to the above code

# same code ...

__DATA__
name            Process                         Pid
---------------- ------------------------------- ----
tneal01        Orange-JI--06                     3443
tneal01        Orange-TE--09                     Down
tneal01        Orange-JI--01                     5533
tneal01        Apple-TE--03                      Down
tneal01        Orange-TE--02                     4992
```

Comment: @connollyc4 Rewritten to address the actual problem, which I misunderstood at first

Comment: Thanks @zdim ! I didn't see this answer for some reason until you mentioned it on the other post. Is there a way I can print to screen to see if this works? like print " Apple-JI--01 is down on the terminal?

Comment: @connollyc4  Sure -- for example, inside `if (@down) { ... }` add `print "@down\n";`.  I added it to the answer.  I tested, but not with your processes of course.

Comment: @connollyc4  Note, this doesn't do what your newer question asks (which I don't fully understand) -- just what _this_ one is about.

Comment: Thanks! that works! the issue I am now running into is that the script will always have the process names up (Orange-TE--02 Apple-JI--01 Orange-JI--06) using process.sh -s. However, when a process goes down the PID column will not have a PID number. Instead it will say "Down" as a PID in the 3rd column. Do you know if it's possible to look at the PID part of process.sh -s and if it says "Down" print the corresponding process name in column 2?

thanks!!!

Comment: @connollyc4  All of this is processing of that table of output -- you can do anything with it.  Let me get it -- So all processes will be listed in fact (none are missing from the list), but some will have "Down" instead of PID -- and you want to identify these?  All such processes or just to check whether any in the list `@watch` has "Down"?

Comment: exactly, I only want to check process in the list @watch have "Down" If any of the `@watch` do say "Down" then print the process name in the error.

Comment: @connollyc4  I have that in working code, but I don't really know how to communicate it.  Adding it here answers a slightly different question than posted, while if you edit this one that invalidates other present answers.  Answering the next (newer) question practically makes a near-duplicate of this one, and leaves this one unresolved. Perhaphs you should take care of marking answers here, for _this_ question, as it stands, and I can post the answer for the new one -- and in the future be careful to not end up in a mix like this.

Comment: Thank you and great point! Your original answer is exactly what I was trying to do when I first wrote this question. I added your post as the my accepted answer and we can use the new post for my modified question. Thanks again!

Comment: @connollyc4  In the meanwhile the other one got put on hold (just as I finished typing in code and explanation!), as it was not a good question in teh beginning.  I'll add that answer here (so that you get it). Then I'll consider asking for the other one to be reopened, but I am not sure whether there is enough merit to that.  Will let you know how that goes.

Comment: @connollyc4  Added the answer to the follow-up question, in the end.  That question (the next, newer one) really should have not been asked or should have been different.  Never mind now, note it for future questions.  Let me know about the addition.  If that other question ever gets reopened I'll move this (added part of the) answer there. Thank you for the attribution.

Comment: Thank you so much @zdim ! Do you know if it's possible to have mailx print out the elements in separate lines? I have tried to do so but it's not giving me an error, nor is it working. This is what I added:

`if (@down) { 
    print "$_ is down\n" for @down;
    # send email
}`

I added this part after the "my down" function.

Does there seem to be an issue with what I added?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is more of the code

`foreach (@down) {
  print "$_\n";
}
if (@down) {
    my $body = "Process are down @down";
    my $cmd_email = "echo $body | " .
        "mailx -s \"Alert process are down\" tneal01\@gmail.com";
    system($cmd_email) == 0  or die "Error sending email -- $!";
}`

Comment: @connollyc4   I added code for it to the answer (tested), with comments.  For a multi-line message you have to write the desired content to a file and then attach the file.  (Or -- I don't know a way to do it otherwise.)  Or use a module, of course.

Comment: Sorry I have been away for a while. Thank you very much for your help. Last question I have is, how can I add the words "key process's are down" as the first line of `services_down.$$`  so that the second line would be the first process down. Thanks!

Comment: @connollyc4  That's fine :).  You print that line to that file right after you opened the file -- so after `open my $fh, '>', $down_file  or die "...";` the next line would be  `print $fh "key ...\n";`.  Then you can print `@data` to the file.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was trying to do. I was reading online that perl can't call another shell script. Is that true? I have the output of `@down` go to another file for formatting. I was trying to figure out after the file is created - sleep 10 seconds and then call another script /users/tneal01/email_format.sh before the scripts exits. Is it possible to call that script at the end of the above perl script?

Comment: @connollyc4  I am not sure I understand, it's been a while and I forgot what exactly this is about.  I'll look, but just to answer right now -- of course you can call a script from Perl. Why not? Are you saying that the output of this Perl script goes to a file and then another script needs to run on it?  Then you can write _to a file_ from inside this script, instead of writing to sceen. Open a file, write to it, and when you are done `close` the filehandle you wrote to. Right after that you can call the other script, using either `system` or backticks (`qx`). Is this what you are asking?

Comment: You added an example which creates a file called `"services_down"` for the purpose of emailing the down process' as an email attachment for a muti-line message. Instead of sending the list of process' down as an email attachment, I created another script called "email_format.sh" which all it does is email the content of "services_down" as the body of the email and removes the services_down file once emailed. 

`shell script content`
`mailx -s 'Status' tneal01@gmail.com, jjake@gmail.com <status_down
sleep 30
rm /users/tneal01/status_down `

Comment: here is the code that creates the services_down file, it's been a while :)
`sub send_email {
    my @data = @_;
    # Write a file  (but use File::Temp) and attach for a multi-line message
    my $down_file = "services_down.$$";
    open my $fh, '>', $down_file  or die "Can't open $down_file: $!";
    print $fh "Process down:\n\n";
    print $fh "$_\n" for @data; 
    close $fh;
}  '
All I'm trying to do is after the file is created email the contents of `services_down` as the body if there are indeed services down and delete the file once emailed (like the above comment)

Comment: @connollyc4 Ah, I see, the `sub send_email` in the first part.  Then, right after `close $fh;` you can call that other script. For example, instead of the email command in `my $cmd = ...` define the command that invokes that other script.  You may well be able to just say `my $cmd = 'email_format.sh';` (if that script is executable).  Then also remove the code that would delete the file.

Comment: Thanks @zdim ! One last question :) is there a way to count the number of process down to add to the  email alert? for example `print $fh "There are (x) processes down:\n\n";`

in place of (x) it would have the count of processes that don't match.

Comment: @connollyc4  The array with that info is called `@data` in the first part (it's `@down` in the second).  The number of elements in an array is obtained by using the array in a _scalar context_ --- say, when you add it, `0 + @data`, or, properly by `scalar @data`.  So you can either say `my $numel = scalar @data;` and use `$numel`, or `print $fh "There are ( " . scalar(@data) . ") processes down:\n\n";`

Answer (score 0):

```
processes_to_be_tracked=('Apple-TE--03' 'Orange-TE--02')
running_processes=( $(process.sh -s | awk '{print $2}') )
non_running=()
for process_name in ${processes_to_be_tracked[@]}; do
    if [[ "${running_processes[*]}" == *$process_name* ]]; then
        echo "$process_name is running"
    else
        echo "$process_name is not running"
        non_running+=($process_name)
    fi
done
send-alert-mail-with-names-of-dead-processes "${non_running[*]}"
```

Comment: I got an error running this script:

`./monitor.sh: line 2: syntax error at line 5: `do' unexpected`.


any idea's why?

Comment: can u paste the a couple of lines before and after the line where u run this script?

Comment: `processes_to_be_tracked=('Apple-TE--03' 'Orange-TE--02')
running_processes=( $(process.sh -s | awk '{print $2}' )
non_running=()
for process_name in ${processes_to_be_tracked[@]}; do
    if [[ "${running_processes[*]}" == *$process_name* ]]; then
        echo "$process_name is running"
    else
        echo "$process_name is not running"
        non_running+=($process_name)
    fi
done`
`
BASH:->monitor.sh
./monitor.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./monitor.sh: line 4: `non_running=()'
Apple-TE--03 is not running
Orange-TE--02 is not running
BASH:-> `

Comment: @connollyc4 I had a syntax error on line 2. I had missed a closing ')' . I have fixed it now. Sorry.